# Dynamically change cell height programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery, heightforrowatindexpath

I've tried plenty of answers on SO but nothing really worked. I'm probably doing something wrong so I need someone to point out what I'm doing wrong..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"text : %@", self.cell.comment.text);

    NSString *text = self.cell.comment.text;
    CGFloat width = self.cell.frame.size.width;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);

    return height;
}
```

I get *"NSInvalidArgumentException" with reason "NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value"* because self.cell.comment.text isn't getting anything by the time I set cell height but it does come through just not when heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called.

Many people have commented on that answer that this method works just fine so I guess I'm missing something?

**Edit**

I'm setting self.cell.comment.text here -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (self.cell == nil) {
    self.cell = [[CommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell

self.cell.comment.text = [object objectForKey:@"comment"];
[self.cell.comment sizeToFit];

return self.cell;}
```

Comment: What is thew value of `text` when you reach that line?

Comment: I get nil. if I comment all that out, without an error I do see all comments on my tableview so they all come through.

Comment: I think you are confusing what self.cell is. Where are you setting `self.cell.comment.text`?

Comment: Try to add an if statement to check the text for `nil` and if yes return a default value

Comment: But it isn't nil tho. I am getting string values from Parse.

Comment: What guarantees do you have that `self.cell` is the cell you have just created in another method? Do you know the inner workings of `UITableView`? What makes you say it works this way now, and will always work the same? What if all cells are created first, then all cells are sized next? `self.cell` would be the last one. What if cells are sized before they are even created? (hint, that's the way it works as of now)

Comment: @Cyrille I understand the problem now thanks.

Comment: @Andy Never thought of that and have no idea how but I'll look into that thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem as you already comment is that function `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before cells are populated.

For every cell that become visible it first call

- get height of this cell
- populate cell

So you know that

a) your text is not yet populated on the cell

b) some other text might be inside, because apple use reusable cells, so UITableView can grab some cell (with different text) and try to resize it and then populate it.

In your case it will grab some other text, resize cell to its size and then populate it with some other text that is (probably) different size then previous text.

But inside cell populations you set text from some business logic (maybe array?), and you can get same text in this method.

if cell population you call

```
cell.comment.text = [self.someArray getObjectAtIndex:index.row];
```

you call this in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
NSString *text = [self.someArray getObjectAtIndex:index.row];
```

---

I see your edit just call :

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"text : %@", self.cell.comment.text);

NSString *text = [object objectForKey:@"comment"];;
CGFloat width = self.cell.frame.size.width;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);

return height;
}
```

---

ADDITION :

Tel say you would like to have cells like this :

```
-------------------------
|  bla bla bla         |
------------------------
| second longer text   |
| over more line       |
------------------------
```

You need to have texts `bla bla` and "second longer text over more line" somewhere saved.

Let say you have array with size 2.

```
NSArray * myTextArray = @[@"bla bla", @"second longer text over more line"];
```

and when populating cells

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

   self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   if (self.cell == nil) {
        self.cell = [[CommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault         reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell

    self.cell.comment.text = [myTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.cell.comment sizeToFit];

    return self.cell;
 }
```

because `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` we need to check text from business (array) side and not visual.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   NSLog(@"text : %@", self.cell.comment.text); // -> this is null because cell is not populated yet.

   NSString *text = [myTextArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; -> this is same text as we will take when populating cell and is not random.
   CGFloat width = self.cell.frame.size.width;
   UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
   NSAttributedString *attributedText =
   [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
   CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
   CGSize size = rect.size;
   CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);

   return height;
}
```

---

EXAMPLE :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property NSArray * myArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myArray = @[@"Some short text",@"Some longer text that take some more space throw more lines",@"bfusdbfjdsfjs fj yfsdy fgsydu fyudsfy fyudsyu fdsy fuysdyuf ydsug fyu sdgyfgsuyff ius fhs fiusdhi ufdshu uifsd ufsdh hfiuds uifdsh fsduih ufdshu hfsd ifshui"];

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *text = self.myArray[indexPath.row];
    CGFloat width = 300;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    CGFloat height = ceilf(size.height);

    return height;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell

    cell.textLabel.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    return cell;
}
```

this example works.

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, instead of setting comment.text directly from [object objectForKey:@"comment"]; which I'm retrieving from Parse, first retrieve the data, put it into an array then comment.text = [newArray getObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];?

Comment: No :D What I am trying say is that you should't rely on visual text inside cell, because this text could be nill or wrong. Instead you need to get text from business logic, doesn't matter if this is a map, array or parse object... You need to be sure that this text is valid and there before program call for height of cell. What you meed "still not working"?

Comment: But what I'm having hard time understanding is that if I insert random cell height as you say just so it can run before cells are populated.. when do they have chance to get re-sized according to their contents?

Comment: I never sad random size.... I will add commend into my answer to explain better...

Comment: I posted an addition. Fill free to ask if something is not clear... :D

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean but my issue is that I retrieve objects from Parse when cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called.. hence I cannot get string values before. There can't be an array with string values before query is complete because that's how I'm getting string values. Am I just really lost here?

Comment: This should not be the case... You can always call parser before and save result of parser. If you will call parser inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, this function will work slow and you should't do this anyway. What is your reason not to call parser before?

Comment: Ah just because parse's tutorial tells us to.. Did not know it was possible to parse somewhere else other than cellForRowAtIndexPath. So how would it work if I get parse objects in queryForTable? Isn't it inconvenient to get all data at once or would paging still work?

Comment: If not in cellForRowAtIndexPath, where do you recommend?

Comment: I not know witch tutorial you are looking at... queryForTable is not standard method so I don't know where it this method either. If there is a lot of data you should consider some paging but loading data or parsing should always be done outside cellForRowAtIndexPath, and I mean really always. :D

Comment: It depends on logic of your program. Let me assume that this is not a real program for company but your way of learning (?) so at first you can try put this at viewDidLoad... For real application you should build your business logic and this would probably doing some business class outside your viewController.

Comment: Consider excepting the answer ;)

Comment: OK. But if anyone sees this and you're using PFQueryTableViewController this is not the answer. You just simply use self.objects as PFQueryTableViewController  does it all for you. No need to do more work. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

In heightForRowAtIndexPath:

For width, I think you can fix it, and don't need this line:

```
 CGFloat width = self.cell.frame.size.width;
```

For the comment text

```
NSString *text = self.cell.comment.text;
```

Try this

```
NSString *text = [object objectForKey:@"comment"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent all day trying to figure this out and finally found out that the solution was super simple, I just needed to know how to use Parse better.

Thanks to Marko, I've learned how UITableView really works and that's great but the solution to my problem was a bit different.

As everyone suggested my problem was assuming that heightForRowAtIndexPath would get called after all cells are populated but I did not need an array to save objects or make any change. Parse apparently saves all retrieved objects before heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called and they're all in **self.objects**.

```
self.cell.comment.text = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And as Andy passionately suggested, I'm now using Auto-size UITableViewCell.

*In your PFQueryTableViewController*

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (object) {
    NSString *commentString = [self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comment"];

    NSLog(@"commentString : %@",commentString);

    CommentCell *cell = [[CommentCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = commentString;


    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    self.height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    self.height += 1;

}

return self.height;}
```

*In your CustomCell*

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    self.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-6-[bodyLabel]-6-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"bodyLabel": self.textLabel }]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-6-[bodyLabel]-6-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{ @"bodyLabel": self.textLabel }]];

}

return self;}


 - (void)layoutSubviews{
[super layoutSubviews];

[self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

self.textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.textLabel.frame);}
```

This definitely works.